# Is there any way to set timout or connectiontimeout in s3 sdk 2.0

Tags: ios, amazon-s3

I want to set timeout property in s3 sdk 2.0 iOS. in previous version if found timeout property but previous version are not handling time skew problem automatically so i m using new sdk but problem is that i am unable to found timout type property . Can any body tell me how can i set timeout or connection timeout property.
i just want to stop uploading task after a specific amount of time but not using timer, i want to use property like NSMutableRequest have conncetiontimeout property

```
  AWSS3TransferManager *transferManager = [AWSS3TransferManager defaultS3TransferManager];
  AWSS3TransferManagerUploadRequest *uploadRequest = [AWSS3TransferManagerUploadRequest new];

uploadRequest.bucket = [Constants pictureBucket];
uploadRequest.key = imageName;
uploadRequest.body = fileUrl;
uploadRequest.contentType = isPNG ? @"image/png" : @"image/jpeg";


//uploadRequest.contentLength = [NSNumber numberWithUnsignedLongLong:imageData.length];

[[transferManager upload:uploadRequest] continueWithBlock:^id(BFTask *task) {
    BOOL isError = (task.error == nil) ? NO : YES;
    NSLog(@"response %@",task.error);

    if (!isError && task.isCompleted)
    {
       NSLog(@"success");
    }
    else
    {
       NSLog(@"failure");        }
    return task;
}];
```

Comment: I am looking for this same answer. The property was removed in v2. I came across a comment somewhere that adding a timeout is in the pipeline and will be in a feature release. If I find a definite answer on this I will update with an answer.

Comment: Hope this link may help you https://mobile.awsblog.com/post/TxX7114UCRBYEW/Understanding-Timeout-and-Retry-Options-in-the-AWS-SDK-for-iOS